# There was no endpoint listening at https://XXX that could accept the message

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

We have a WCF service (client Application) which accesses a Web service via HTTPS. Everything works fine in our development environment, but when the WCF service is deployed to the production environment we are getting the below error.

We can access the Web service from a Web browser in the production environment, but not from the WCF service.

> There was no endpoint listening at https://XXX that could accept the
>   message.  This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.:   Server stack
>   trace:       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:        at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: The Problem may be caused by wrong binding Settings, blocked ports, insufficient permissions or a wrong address (https instead of http). To solve this issue, we need more info. Wrap your web Service call in a try-catch block and write an error-log with the InnerException for more detail on the real problem or use Remote-Debugging.